# Error, when trying to evaluate my solution of exercise from Intro to computer science (Python Udacity's course)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm learning Python and trying to pass course "Intro to computer science" (CS101) from Udacity. (https://www.udacity.com/course/intro-to-computer-science--cs101)
One of the exercises is 10 Row Abacus. 
I wrote my solution and it working pretty well in my Python IDLE, but estimator did't accept my code, returned this error message:

```
   "Incorrect. Your submission did not return the correct result for the input 12345678. The expected output was:

    '|00000*****   |\n|00000*****   |\n|00000****   *|\n|00000***   **|\n|00000**   ***|\n|00000*   ****|\n|00000   *****|\n|0000   0*****|\n|000   00*****|\n|00   000*****|'

    Your submission passed 1 out of 3 test cases"
```

I can't figure out where is the problem
If someone can say me where is my mistake, I'll appreciate it !

Description of exercise:

```
     10-row School abacus
                         by
                      Michael H

       Description partially extracted from from wikipedia 

  Around the world, abaci have been used in pre-schools and elementary

 In Western countries, a bead frame similar to the Russian abacus but
 with straight wires and a vertical frame has been common (see image).
 Helps schools as an aid in teaching the numeral system and arithmetic

         |00000*****   |     row factor 1000000000
         |00000*****   |     row factor 100000000
         |00000*****   |     row factor 10000000 
         |00000*****   |     row factor 1000000
         |00000*****   |     row factor 100000
         |00000*****   |     row factor 10000
         |00000*****   |     row factor 1000
         |00000****   *|     row factor 100     * 1
         |00000***   **|     row factor 10      * 2
         |00000**   ***|     row factor 1       * 3
                                        -----------    
                             Sum                123 

 Each row represents a different row factor, starting with x1 at the
 bottom, ascending up to x1000000000 at the top row.     


 TASK:
 Define a procedure print_abacus(integer) that takes a positive integer
 and prints a visual representation (image) of an abacus setup for a 
 given positive integer value.

 Ranking
 1 STAR: solved the problem!
 2 STARS: 6 < lines <= 9
 3 STARS: 3 < lines <= 6
 4 STARS: 0 < lines <= 3
```

My code:

def print_abacus(value):

```
abacuses = {
    "0" : "|00000*****   |",
    "1" : "|00000****   *|",
    "2" : "|00000***   **|",
    "3" : "|00000**   ***|",
    "4" : "|00000*   ****|",
    "5" : "|00000   *****|",
    "6" : "|0000   0*****|",
    "7" : "|000   00*****|",
    "8" : "|00   000*****|",
    "9" : "|0   0000*****|"}


lst = []



s = str(value)
for i in s:    
    for key in abacuses: 
        if i == key: 
            lst.append(abacuses[key])


while len(lst) <= 10:
    lst.insert(0, abacuses["0"])



for abacus in lst:
    print abacus
```

P.S. Sorry for my English

Comment: What is the output for 12345678 when you run it manually?

Answer (score 1):

There must be 10 items in `lst` to get the right result, but when you do:

```
while len(lst) <= 10:
    lst.insert(0, abacuses["0"])
```

It adds an extra entry when there are 10 numbers, this means that there are always 11 items when this loop finishes.

Just change `<=` to `<` so that it only adds entries when there are not enough (while there are less then 10 entries add one.)

Comment: Yes, i actually found it by myself. Stupid mistake :( Anyway, thank you :)

Comment: No problem, was just about to update my answer explaining how I tested your code and found this out and suggest you work on your debugging skills but it seems that won't be necessary! :D

Answer (score 0):

This my 4 starts code since it required only 3 code lines inside the method and might help someone:

1-) The first line just create an array where each number is an string (the number is the same as the index of the array). For example number 3 is simply 
                     numbers[3]= "|00000**   ***|".

2-) The second line this code just creating an string with the missing zeros, for example for number 123, it becomes an array of characters of ten digits: "0000000123".

3-) In the third line each character is converted into a number again and it is used as the index for the numbers array and print one by one.

```
def print_abacus(value):
   #line code 1
   numbers= ["|00000*****   |",
            "|00000****   *|",
            "|00000***   **|",
            "|00000**   ***|",
            "|00000*   ****|",
            "|00000   *****|",
            "|0000   0*****|",
            "|000   00*****|",
            "|00   000*****|",
            "|0   0000*****|",]
   #line code 2 and 3        
   for n in ("0"*(10-len(str(value)))+str(value)):
       print numbers[int(n)]
```